# internal server error on live server with jquery ajax php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

at my local my form, jquery/ajax, php is working smoothly, how come when on the production server am getting an internal server 500 error , that's the only message i get from the firebug console and nothing else, how to debug this? is there something wrong with my ajax script ?

```
    if(userid == ""){
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "classes/ajax.submitcv.php",
      timeout: 8000,
      data: "userid="+userid+"&cvusername="+cvusername+"&resumetitle="+resumetitle+"&resumeintro="+resumeintro+
            "&name="+name+"&dob="+dob+"&contacttel1="+contacttel1+"&contacttel1type="+contacttel1type+
            "&contacttel2="+contacttel2+"&contacttel2type="+contacttel2type+"&contacttel3="+contacttel3+
            "&contacttel3type="+contacttel3type+"&primaryemail="+primaryemail+"&secondaryemail="+secondaryemail+
            "&skype="+skype+"&facebook="+facebook+"&linkedin="+linkedin+"&twitter="+twitter+
            "&messenger="+messenger+"&yahoo="+yahoo+"&aol="+aol+"&summaryofpositionsought="+
            summaryofpositionsought+"&summaryofskills="+summaryofskills+"&gender="+gender,
      success: function(){
           $('form#wsrecruitcvhead').fadeOut("normal",function(){
           $('div.successpostregister').fadeIn(1000);
        });
      },
//      error: function(result){
//        alert(result.status +);
//      }
      });
      return false;
     } else {

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "classes/ajax.submitcv.php",
      timeout: 8000,
      data: "userid="+userid+"$cvusername="+cvusername+"&resumetitle="+resumetitle+"&resumeintro="+resumeintro+
            "&name="+name+"&dob="+dob+"&contacttel1="+contacttel1+"&contacttel1type="+contacttel1type+
            "&contacttel2="+contacttel2+"&contacttel2type="+contacttel2type+"&contacttel3="+contacttel3+
            "&contacttel3type="+contacttel3type+"&primaryemail="+primaryemail+"&secondaryemail="+secondaryemail+
            "&skype="+skype+"&facebook="+facebook+"&linkedin="+linkedin+"&twitter="+twitter+
            "&messenger="+messenger+"&yahoo="+yahoo+"&aol="+aol+"&summaryofpositionsought="+
            summaryofpositionsought+"&summaryofskills="+summaryofskills+"&gender="+gender,
      success: function(){
           $('form#wsrecruitcvhead').fadeOut("normal",function(){
           $('div.successpost').fadeIn(1000);
        });
      },
      });
      return false;
        }
```

help :(

Comment: what about debugging the server side code

Comment: how? because all I got from the firebug console is 500 internal server error and nothing else :(

Comment: problem solved,, i was given the access to the php error logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to `tail` the server logs to find out what the error is. You should be able to obtain the full stack trace and single out the cause of the error.

Comment: Then, in firebug just click on the request that shows the 500 error (should be in red color), and then open the "Response" tab. Check if you get any details about the error in the body returned from the server.

Comment: there's no response at the response tab, so what i did instead, i asked for the error logs. and found the real error..it was a syntax error in my php file..thanks for the help